# replace some arrays with preg_replace (first line doesn't work)

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

i'm scripting some code that you allows you to upload a txt-file an read this in an array. now i want to change some line of this array with preg_replace but the first array will not change.

here is the code http://pastebin.com/jkxAE1h5

HTML:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="my_text[]" type="file" />
<input type="submit" />
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$geladene_seite = $_FILES['my_text']['tmp_name'][0];
$array_liste = array(0);
$my_text_file = file($geladene_seite);

foreach ($my_text_file as $single_file) {
  $single_file = trim($single_file);    //  leerzeichen entfernen
  if (strlen($single_file) > 0){
    $single_file = str_replace(chr(10), '', $single_file);
    $single_file = str_replace(chr(13), '', $single_file);
    $menge = array_push ($array_liste, $single_file);
  }
}

echo '<hr><pre>';
print_r ($array_liste);
echo '</pre>';

$text1 = str_replace($array_liste[1], '<b>'.$array_liste[1].'</b>', $array_liste[10]);
$text2 = str_replace($array_liste[2], '<b>'.$array_liste[2].'</b>', $array_liste[11]);
$text3 = str_replace($array_liste[3], '<b>'.$array_liste[3].'</b>', $array_liste[12]);

echo '<p>'.$text1.'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$text2.'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$text3.'</p>';

?>
```

Sample Data:

```
text one
text two
text three

this is for description one
this is for description two
this is for description three

header for number one
header for number two
header for number three

many more infos for the text one many more infos for the text one many more infos for the text one many more infos for the text one many more infos for the text one many more infos for the text one
many more infos for the text two many more infos for the text two many more infos for the text two many more infos for the text two many more infos for the text two many more infos for the text two
many more infos for the text three many more infos for the text three many more infos for the text three many more infos for the text three many more infos for the text three many more infos for the text three
```

best regards, steven

Comment: There is no preg_replace in your code.

Comment: Could you make the question simpler please? Details of the input, what you expect the output to be and what it really is.

Comment: it doesn't matter, if str_replace or preg_replace. it's the same error in my code. here is an image http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/8179/arrayu.jpg
i thing in the array 1 is a little dot. can anybody say what this is?
thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
$array_liste = array(0);
```

Change it to:

```
$array_liste = array();
```